# Cannot make startActivity() with Chooser ask just once per app

Tags: android, android-intent

When you do `startActivity()` with chooser, Android would list all apps entitled to handle your `Intent` along with options to set this assignment permanent or once-time (on ICS its `Always` and `Just once` action button, on 2.x it's a checkbox). However for this code:

```
public class Redirector {
    public static void showActivityWithChooser( Context context, int chooserLabelTitleId, Intent intent ) {
      try {
        context.startActivity( Intent.createChooser( intent, 
                     context.getResources().getString( chooserLabelTitleId )) );
      } catch( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    public static void viewInExternalApplication( Context context, String url ) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(   Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
      intent.setData( Uri.parse( url ) );
      intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET );
      showActivityWithChooser( context, R.string.open_chooser_title, intent );
    }
}
```

I see no `Always | Just once` buttons and cannot make my selection permanent. What elementary I overlooked that made Android unable to make user choice persistent?

See the pics: left dialog is what I'd like to see, but right is what I get now (different number of applications in both dialogs is irrelevant):

[image]

Comment: `Always` means make the selection permanent. Your app has no way to control this dialog, its part of Android directly.

Comment: Indeed I did. However, the second half of my comment stands; this is not a dialog you can control from your app. The problem is that you're calling showActivityWithChooser, which is not intended to let the user change their default but is instead intended to force the user to choose.

Comment: @mah: hm, it just came to my mind it can be bug in my head :) I somehow assume that "Chooser" will not pop up if user made permanent previously. Which can simply be wrong, what I am now gonna check.

Comment: @mah: and that was it. Thanks for the hint...

Comment: you should not start a chooser unless you have intention to process multi applications to show the user ie customizing the list of applications you want to share to.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For a record - it was over-interpretation type of bug (of mine). The chooser I was using is exactly what can be seen on the image on the right side. And it was showing up all the time because... I was calling it all the time. I incorrectly assumed that chooser offers `Always | Just once` functionality and would not show up if user tapped "Always" (and will show up if s/he used `Just once`). But it is wrong. Chooser will **always** show up because that's its role - to let user choose.

The `Always | Just once` functionality is different thing -> it is a feature of the Android framework for `startActivity()` (and `startActivityForResult()` etc) and it would show up automatically when needed (when there's more than one app, or precisely, more than one matching `intent-filter` declared in app manifest, that matches certain `Intent`). It would not show up if you got just one (or if user already choose `Always`).

So you, as developer do not need to care nor handle the case in any special way. To fix the issue I simply changed my `viewInExternalApplication()` code to just call `startActivity()`:

```
try {
  context.startActivity( intent );
} catch (.... )
```

and let the framework do the rest.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to understand! 10x