# shutting down android functionality like qs tiles, volume panel and navigation's

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, android-rom

I am working on an well-being app that shuts your phone up for a given period of time (eg. 30min, 1hr, 1.5hr)

In this state user can only see a screen with remaining time on it and cannot

- Access QS tiles
- Access Volume panel
- Navigate out of the Activity

something similar to Oneplus
[Zen mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P51Fk.png)

***things i have thought of for doing this***

- Killing the SystemUI process.(by doing so the QS and volume panel
  would be dealt with most probably, maybe need root for that tho?
  also SystemUI automatically restarts itself, quite stubborn)
- Making app a launcher Dynamically?(technically you can't navigate
  out of a launcher and on reboot you come back to it)

how can I get around accomplishing this? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making application the default launcher of the phone is more practical solution to what you're trying to achieve. I've done this previously in a Flutter application which was going to be installed on kiosk devices to get orders from customers and it worked perfectly. It's a bit tricky to make it work and there's lots of things to do. Here is a list of things I did back then:

1. Use `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` flag to the window to bypass the lock screen.
2. Inside of `onResume` add `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` flags to hide the status bar.
3. Make your `MainActivity` launcher by adding `LAUNCHER` category to in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Also you can add other attributes I used (Search for them if you don't know what are they supposed to do).

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
       android:excludeFromRecents="true"
       android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
       android:launchMode="singleInstance"
       android:showOnLockScreen="true"
       android:showWhenLocked="true"
       android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
       android:turnScreenOn="true"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
4. Listen for window focus changes in your `MainActivity` and bring your application to front if it lost the focus.

   ```
   private fun moveToFront() {
     val closeDialog = Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)
     sendBroadcast(closeDialog)
     (activity.applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager)
             .moveTaskToFront(activity.taskId, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME)
     window.setFlags(
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
   }

   override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
     if (!hasFocus) {
       moveToFront()
     }
   }
   ```
5. I was also checking if my application is the default launcher.

   ```
   private fun isAppDefault(): Boolean {
     val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME)
     val res: ResolveInfo = packageManager.resolveActivity(intent, 0)
     return res.activityInfo != null && (packageName
           == res.activityInfo.packageName)
   }
   ```
6. And you're gonna need to communicate between Flutter and the platform using `MethodChannel` to enable and disable force mode and get the state of the application.

Comment: I agree, launcher seems to be the answer, any ideas on how can I make the app a launcher dynamically? for i.e. when user sets a timer the app would make itself a default launcher and step away as soon as the timer completes, I'm guessing I would have to give the app permission to edit system settings.

Comment: There is no way you can make your app the default launcher without user consent. But you can show a prompt based on the result of `isAppDefault` for user to remove if there is another default launcher and then you can start an `Intent` to prompt the user for choosing default launcher. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786828/how-to-bring-up-the-set-default-launcher-prompt @Brijraj